# Pandas - Replace number-strings with the name ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe of all Strings some of them are TAG(machines/computers), some other items, and the others are ID's.  I am looking to change all the strings that are ID's to "ID" instead of the number-string.

```
type(df.columnOne[1])
str
```

This is what my df column looks like:

```
df
  columnOne
0 TAG
1 1115268
2 13452
3 system
4 TAG
5 355511
6 95221543
7 5124
8 111333544
9 TAG
10 local
11 434312
```

Desired output:

```
df
  columnOne
0 TAG
1 ID
2 ID
3 system
4 TAG
5 ID
6 ID
7 ID
8 ID
9 TAG
10 Local
11 ID
```

I would normally do something where if it doesn't equal TAG or system or Local then ID.  But it is always changing with names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `str.isnumeric`:

```
df.loc[df.columnOne.str.isnumeric(),'columnOne'] = 'ID'

>>> df
   columnOne
0        TAG
1         ID
2         ID
3     system
4        TAG
5         ID
6         ID
7         ID
8         ID
9        TAG
10     local
11        ID
```

Comment: Yes, based on the OP's example, should be OK. Good to point it out though, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try replace

```
df.columnOne = df.columnOne.str.replace('\d+', 'ID')

0        TAG
1         ID
2         ID
3     system
4        TAG
5         ID
6         ID
7         ID
8         ID
9        TAG
10     local
11        ID
```

Comment: I like the way of `replace`

Answer (score 3):

As RafaelC mentioned in the comment , if contain float

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.columnOne,errors='coerce').notna(),'columnOne']='ID'
df
Out[536]: 
   columnOne
0        TAG
1         ID
2         ID
3     system
4        TAG
5         ID
6         ID
7         ID
8         ID
9        TAG
10     local
11        ID
```

Answer (score 1):

***Solution using apply:***
*(just for completeness, `str.replace` and `str.isnumeric` solutions are much more simple)*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnOne': ['TAG', 
                                 '1111', 
                                 'system']})

def ids_replace(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return 'ID'
    except ValueError:
        return x

print(df.apply(ids_replace, axis=1))

> columnOne
0   TAG
1   ID
2   system
```